# direct proof when a is even and b is a multiple of 3 then ab is a multiple of 6

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the statement: for all integers a and b, if a is even and b is a multiple of 3, then ab is a multiple of 6. a) prove the statement using direct proof and b) state the converse. Is it true? prove or disprove

I have been staring at this problem for three days, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** for a)

$a=2k$ and $b=3m$ means $ab=?$

**Hint** for b)

consider $a=1$ and $b=6$